# Reclassifying a raster based on values in another raster

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, reclassify

I am attempting to create a new raster based on the values of two rasters I have already created. I am using ArcGIS 10.1

- Raster1 is an area with my true values.
- Raster2 was created by reclassifying Raster1 using focal statistics.  This reclassified the raster1 pixel values according to the maximum pixel value within the kernel.

The goal for my reclassification is to compare the values in Raster1 to the values in Raster2.  If the Raster1 value is < 50% of the value in Raster 2 then the pixel in the new raster is set to 0, else the value is kept as the value in Raster1.

I am hoping that I can work something out using the ArcGIS toolbox.  I am not an advanced user so I don't understand programming.

Comment: Welcome, what have you tried already?

Comment: In all truth, I don't really know where to start.  I had a look at the raster calculator, thinking that would be the place to do it, but was unsure how to do if/then statements.

Comment: See the help for [con](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Con/009z00000005000000/).

Comment: I have now given the con(,) an attempt, but I think I am having issues with my syntax.  If I use the following con("Raster1", 0,1,"Raster1"*0.5<"Raster2") would that work.  If I set the values for the new raster to 0 or 1 it is fine for what I am doing.  I am really unsure about the where clause.